# MySQL query without group by fundtion

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

How can i write a sql query in my sql where i have many columns like(name, age, weight, salary, demography, loan status) from various table and last_recorded_date column without using group by function ?

I dont want to use

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = sys.list_add(@@session.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');
```

The method i use right now is

```
select a.name,a.age,a.weight, b.salary,c.demography,d.loan_type,d.loan_amt,
max(d.recordeddate) as last_recorded date
from cust_details a,applicanttable b, applicanttype b,masterloan d
where a.name=b.name and a.age=c.age and a.city=d.region
group by d.loanid;
```

Is there any other way to write the above query without using group by function ?

Comment: Care to tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: there is a good cause why you need group functions, if you can't decide which value you need, how should mysql know it for you.

Comment: Do you have s syntactically correct version of this query?

Comment: main agenda for me is that we keep recording data monthly, and i want latest record date, while running code in javascript it throws me a full group by error. I dont have a possibility to change that. Hence asking if I can write a query where max function can be used in a query without group by